# Reduce repeating code in React native

Tags: javascript, html, react-native

Currently I'm working on a project where some of my code blocks being repeated several times. Since duplicating same code again ad again is not a best practice, I though to create a function outside of `render` function and call it whenever I need with string values.

Ex:

```
getInfo(name,age,address)
{
   return (
      <View> 
        <Text> {name} </Text>
        <Text> {age} </Text>
        <Text> {address} </Text>
      </View>
   )
}
```

As above sketched code shows, I want to get a return like this. After that I tried to simply call the function inside render using `getInfo('adam',46,'UK')`. But seems like it does not work.

**Problem**

How can I correctly create `getInfo` method which will return HTML code with String parameters given? and how to call that inside `render` function?

**Update**

When I call the function inside `render`. It does not do anything. I just called the function as I showed.

Comment: You're looking for a custom Component, a basic building block of React. Here's how to declare and use one: https://codesandbox.io/s/n56m5q43xp (added using a function in `render` method)

Comment: You said it seems like it does not work. Please show what happens when you use it (if there’s an error then show that too).

Comment: Relevant docs entry: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find a problem with your getInfo method if you want to do exactly what you say.

So,

```
getInfo(name,age,address)
{
   return (
      <View> 
         <Text> {name} </Text>
         <Text> {age} </Text>
         <Text> {address} </Text>
      </View>
    )
}
```

and you cannot simply call the function inside return. Just check below example.

```
render()
{
   return (
      <View>
      {
        this.getInfo('adam',46,'UK')
      }
      </View>
  )
}
```

This will give you what you expect.